# Inline code not executed in a shiny app with Rmarkdown report

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Dear all shiny developers!

I have a question about a shiny app with a Rmarkdown report downloadable.
The app is based on this https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html, taken here as an exemple.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(filename) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
        # can happen when deployed).

        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "Template.Rmd")
        print(tempReport)
        file.copy("Template.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        
        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$slider)
        
        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = filename,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

with my .Rmd document

````
---
title: ''
output: pdf_document
geometry: "left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm"
params:
  n: NA
---


```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `r params$n` random points.
````

The code is running ok, the document is created but when I open it, I can see that the code within the chunk is ok but not in the inline code, see below:

[image]

However, in this exemple https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html we see that the inline code is good (I don't have the code of the Rmarkdown unfortunatelly).

I saw this subject (https://community.rstudio.com/t/embedding-shiny-with-inline-not-rendering-with-html-output/41175) that could be similar but it is html and the answer does not seem to fit.

Do you have an idea why it does not function ? Or any track to explore ?

Many thanks !!

Comment: You need `r params$n`.

Comment: Sorry was a typo when I copy paste. However, I checked on my script it is not working even with the r params$n. Do you understand ?

Comment: Ohhh damn it seems that the temp.files is not erased and that the version is not correct since when I change the Rmd it does not change the pdf created!! Damn I am trying to find more solution and I ll post it if I understand !!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful  to the file.copy function !

Thanks to the remark of Limey, I notice that the Rmarkdown that had a typo few moments ago was not updated! Careful that the file.copy is correct!

Here is the script working:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(filename) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
        # can happen when deployed).

        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "rules.Rmd")
        print(tempReport)
        file.copy("Data/rules.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        
        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$slider)
        
        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = filename,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

and the Rmarkown

````
---
title: ''
output: pdf_document
geometry: "left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm"
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```
A plot of `r params$n` random points.
````

Thanks to all of you that gave time to this subject!